# Varying roles; Varying tables

Tags: postgresql, roles, sql-grant

**Environment:**

psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.3

**Question:**

I have a varying collection of Postgres users (i.e. roles) to whom I wish to grant readonly access to a varying collection of tables.

1. That is, assume I have a collection of users U (U1, U2, U3, etc.) and a collection of tables T (Ta, Tb, etc.).  I want to grant readonly access to tables T to users U even if the sets T and U vary over time.
2. That is, lets say I add a user U4 to U. I want U4 to automatically have access to all tables T.

   Alternatively, let's say I have a new table Tn and I wish to grant access to all users in U.
3. Alternatively, I have a table Tz in T and I want to remove privileges to Tz from all users in U.

How do I accomplish 1,2, and 3?

Comment: Always assign non-login roles (i.e. groups) to various things, then grant those groups to users. That way you just revoke that role and poof no more access.

Comment: [Role Membership](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-membership.html). Also look for [default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).